# Ignore Insertion if select subquery return null - Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

**user**

```
user_id  |  name
1        |  John
2        | Matt
```

**food**

```
food_id  | food_name
1        | A
2        | B
```

**fav_food**

```
user_id(-> user) | food_id(->food)

    2            |   1
```

My insertion query:

```
INSERT INTO `fav_food`(user_id,food_id) VALUES(?,(SELECT id from `food` where food_name=?))
```

When the `SELECT id from food where food_name=?` subquery returns null insertion fails with an error which should be.
My question is, How can I ignore the insertion only when the subquery returns null or no rows? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
INSERT INTO fav_food (user_id, food_id) 
  SELECT ?, (SELECT food_id FROM food WHERE food_name = ?) 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM food WHERE food_name = ?)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/omN2RoepsDAis4MK3cFxVM/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO `fav_food`(user_id,food_id) VALUES(?,(SELECT id from `food` where food_name=? AND food_name IS NOT NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tried before, you can do that by using an if statement in a stored procedure, the code might look something like the following:

```
    if exists (SELECT id from `food` where food_name=?) then
         INSERT INTO `fav_food`(user_id,food_id) VALUES(?,(SELECT id from `food` where food_name=?))
    end if;
```